# Can a massive particle have zero charge without being made of electrons and protons?

Tags: particle-physics, charge

I know a neutron decays outside the nucleus into a proton and an electron and also that a neutrino has no charge but is there a particle that simply has no charge?

Comment: I don’t understand the question. Are you asking whether there are elementary particles *other than neutrinos* that have mass but not charge? Or are you including composite particles? If so, do they have to have a certain lifetime to count?

Comment: I thought it was still an open question about neutrinos having mass/

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino

Comment: okay, massive but not very massive and not a very satisfying sort of particle -- you could not have a bunch of the together to get a visible or easily measurable "lump" of neutrinos.

Comment: You’re not going to get a lump of $Z$’s or $H$’s either. But you don’t need a lump to do measurements. I haven’t figured out the point of your question.

Comment: the question basically is whether the matter that we encounter must always have a charge and it sounds like it must -- sometimes the negative and positive charges cancel each other but there is no such thing as a "chargeless" chunk of "stuff" is what it sounds like.

Comment: Yes, that’s right. But we know of no deep reason for this. It just appears to be true. We can easily imagine a universe with a heavy, stable, neutral elementary particle.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, an example of an [elementary particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle) with mass but without electric charge is the [Z boson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W_and_Z_bosons#Z_bosons) or the [Higgs boson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_boson).

Comment: Is the Z boson ever found in a "free" state or does is it only inside an atom or proton and only seen briefly in particle accelerator collisions? If it is never in a free state, then I would amend my question to ask whether there can be "a piece" of matter than has no charge but also is not composed of charged particles that balance out.

Comment: @releseabe The $Z$ lasts only about a trillionth of a trillionth of a second. We don’t detect it as a free particle.

Comment: @releseabe To my knowledge there is no appreciably sized "piece of matter" that could be formed from particles without electric charge. They need something to hold them together which in most cases in physics is the electromagnetic interaction, ignoring gravity which is far too weak on an individual particle level to hold particles in place particularly well.

Comment: I guess you could in principle have an uncharged black hole but that's a fairly idealised situation that I'm not sure really exists.